# iOS Development: How can I shorten a URL from my code?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, twitter

I'm building an iPhone app and I'd like to include functionality that allows users to login to twitter and tweet a link to my app. In order to do this, however, the tweet will need to shorten the URL to my app on the App Store.  How can I write code to shorten a URL for a tweet?

I've done a search for this and found [a tutorial on iCodeBlog](http://icodeblog.com/2010/02/04/iphone-coding-recipe-shortening-urls/), as well as some [questions posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252470/implementing-url-shorteners-in-my-iphone-application), however, they're all either more work than I think is needed or they're using http://api.tr.im, which is no longer available.  I'm hoping there's a newer approach to this that is as simple as the iCodeBlog solution.

Thanks for your wisdom!

Comment: It sounds like you only need the URL to your app to be shortened. Why not shorten it on, say, bit.ly, and use that short URL in the tweet?

Comment: I agree with donkim. It's only one link, at most a few links.

Comment: i was under the impression that shortened URLs are inherently temporary.  if not, then you're right.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I just google a few minutes because I'm also interested in that topic. And I found this: [TinyURL API](http://scripting.com/stories/2007/06/27/tinyurlHasAnApi.html) I think that's the easiest way to implement something like this. I think I'll write a little class for this to use it in further projects. :-D

Comment: Thanks Dude, TinyAPI is Amazing and Gives Response in very Short Time...!!!!!!thanks Again....!!!!!!!!!
+1 For this...!!!!!

Comment: don't use TinyUrl, they are inconsistent with the response you receive.

Comment: Tiny URL gives HTTP. I need in HTTPs. Any work Arounds ?

Comment: You can just change the http you receive from the api to https. Works as expected.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to Sandro and woodleader:

```
NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=%@",active_content_url];
NSString *shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint]
                                                  encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                     error:nil];
/* use shortURL */
```

Comment: simple and perfect answer

Comment: my url contain params encoded with base64 and using this method return `shortURL ===> (null)`

Answer (score 3):

You simple do a HTTP Request to an Service of your choice. I have choosen l.pr in this example. Many other Services have such an easy API. The magic here is in a method that is a part of NSString. This method is called stringWithContentsOfURL. It will easily allow you to grab the text of any remote source.

As an example:

```
NSString *url    = @"http://woodleader.org";
NSString *apiEndpoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/api.l.pr/shorten?apikey=axbymc46859i685jfk9fk&longurl=%@",url];
NSString *shortURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:apiEndpoint]
         encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
         error:nil];
NSLog(@"Long: %@ - Short: %@",url,shortURL);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a blog post on how to shorten a url using bit.ly

http://www.aproposmac.com/2012/01/shorten-url-using-bitly-in-objective-c.html

Answer (score 2):

#### Very Simple..

Try this sample.. Its working well for me.

**Sample:** [URL Shortner in ios programatically](https://github.com/theaudience/URL-Shortener)

(Or)

**Http Post Method via google api:** http://www.warewoof.com/goo-gl-url-shortener-in-ios/

Answer (score 1):

If you decided to use Google Shortener API, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071395/get-url-shortened-with-google-api-afnetworking-in-swift) can be an answer. They use AFNetworking, written in Swift to get URL shortened. The sample code as following:

```
func getShorURLFromGoogle(longURL: String) {
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer() as AFJSONRequestSerializer
    let params = [
        "longUrl": longURL
    ]
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    manager.POST("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=\(appDelegate.googleMapsApiKey)", parameters: params, success: {
        (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
        if let responseObject = responseObject as? NSDictionary {
            //println(responseObject["id"] as String)
            self.shortURL = responseObject["id"] as? String //That's what you want  
        }
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            println("Error while requesting shortened: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })
}
```

Comment: I have tried your answer but i faced a problem .. can you check back for your answer please

Comment: Also, i tried to read your article but the website seems to be down

Answer (score 1):

I use the below code.

```
    #define BITLY_LOGIN     @"pooja12"
    #define BITLY_APIKEY    @"R_c7045505f04343a7833721225740215c"
- (NSString *) shortURL {
        NSString *uri = [self absoluteString];
            NSString *fmt = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?login=%@&apiKey=%@&longUrl=%@&format=txt", BITLY_LOGIN, BITLY_APIKEY, uri];
            NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: fmt];
            //NSString *shortUri = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: requestUrl];
            //NSString *shortUri = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: requestUrl];
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSString *shortUri = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:requestUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
            shortUri = [shortUri stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}
// here i call the above methods

      NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"-url-"];
      NSString *shortenStr = [shareUrl shortURL];
      NSLog(@"Short url is %@", shortenStr);
```