# Shorten URL in Swift

Tags: swift, string, url

Inside my app I retrieve URL's and I would like to present them but in a short way. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764451/ios-development-how-can-i-shorten-a-url-from-my-code) SO-Question for `Objective-C`.

What is the easiest way to get this done in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
let link = "https://google.com"
let url = URL(string: "https://tiny url.com/api-create.php?url=\(link)")!
let shortLink = try! String(contentsOf: url)
print(shortLink)
```

Note you’ll need to remove the space between tiny and url to make it work as SO complains when you post shortened URLs and it thinks that is a shortened one.

You’ll also not want to force unwrap either and handle the errors appropriately.

Comment: thanks ill give it a try! What are best practices for error handling/safe unwrapping here?

Comment: `if let`, `guard let` and for `try` you may need a `do/catch` depending on how you handle it. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/10/2/unwrapping-optionals https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/10/3/unwrapping-with-guard https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/10/8/optional-try